# Python Findall not finding anything

Tags: python, regex

I am learning about Regex and am stuck with this code:

```
import re

resume = '''
    (738) 383-5729
    (373) 577-0492
    (403) 443-2759
    (375) 880-8576
    (641) 576-2342
    (951) 268-8744
    '''

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'\d')

mo = phoneRegex.findall(resume)

print(mo.group())
```

When I try with `search` instead of `findall`, it works. But it can't find any match with `findall`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

[`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a simple list of strings matching the pattern.

It has no `group()` method, just omit that:

```
>>> print(mo)
['7', '3', '8', '3', '8', '3', '5', '7', '2', '9', '3', '7', '3', '5', '7',
 '7', '0', '4', '9', '2', '4', '0', '3', '4', '4', '3', '2', '7', '5', '9',
 '3', '7', '5', '8', '8', '0', '8', '5', '7', '6', '6', '4', '1', '5', '7', 
 '6', '2', '3', '4', '2', '9', '5', '1', '2', '6', '8', '8', '7', '4', '4']
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could use the group method with findall.

Comment: @user84296 Well... you *can't*. That's kind of the point of my answer :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to match phone numbers in `resume`, for that you can use:

```
resume = '''
    (738) 383-5729
    (373) 577-0492
    (403) 443-2759
    (375) 880-8576
    (641) 576-2342
    (951) 268-8744
    '''

mo = re.findall(r'\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}', resume)

for x in mo:
    print(x)
```

---

Output:

```
(738) 383-5729
(373) 577-0492
(403) 443-2759
(375) 880-8576
(641) 576-2342
(951) 268-8744
```

---

1. [Python Demo](https://ideone.com/JPLOY2)
2. [Regex Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hlqlfH/1)

Answer (score 1):

Since (it looks like) you're just out for the numbers, you could do something like

```
>>> [''.join(c for c in l if c in '0123456789')  for l in resume.strip().splitlines()]
['7383835729', '3735770492', '4034432759', '3758808576', '6415762342', '9512688744']
```

That might save you some trouble from internationally formed numbers (such as `+46-(0)7-08/123 456` and the like).

Answer (score -2):

`Re.findall()` module is used when you want to iterate over the lines by line, it will return a list of all the matches not group.

So in your case it returns as list

```
print(mo[0])
```